# ASP.NET & TCP Server Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, tcp

My server has two applications running on it:

1. TCP socket server that continuously accepts and sends messages to and 
      from clients (C# .NET Winforms)
2. ASP.NET application

What I need is:

- When a message is received from a client via the TCP connection (app 1) I want the ASP .NET application (app 2) to reflect this data dynamically. I realise that I can set database entries via the TCP socket, which will then be picked up by the ASP.NET application.
- A way of sending messages to clients from the ASP .NET application to clients that are available inside of the TCP socket server

e.g.  A simple chat program where a client sends *“Hi”* and server responds *“Welcome”*. The ASP .NET should show a log of this conversation as it happens. Immediately. And if I click a button on the ASP application, it should send a message on behalf of the socket server to the client *“You have been accepted onto the server”*

For the most part, the messages are going to be fairly short like the ones shown here.

What is the best way to do A and B?

Comment: Immediately like within milliseconds? Asp.net push or pull to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your "messages" are mostly textual, you may want to take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

SignalR is a new library for asp.net to enable real-time web functionality.

It uses websockets (or long polling if websockets is unavailable at server/client).

It has support for different client types.

Comment: You might want to mention that SignalR is now part of the ASP.NET family

Comment: @jgauffin Yeah i guess i should but the url says everything he needs to know.

Comment: well. the answer could be classified as a link only answer right now (hence being flagged for removal). you should explain what signalr is.

Comment: this kind of answer should definitely not be removed, even if no description was given this answer is very helpful to many people who aren't aware of SignalR (such as myself)

Answer (score 3):

SignlaR is a good solution if you're getting the messages from another SignalR client (web page).

But what if these messages are being sent from a 3rd system over TCP/IP?
Then you need to open a TCP port in the ASP.NET Web Application and after receiving a message you have to push it to the web clients.

But the question is, what is the best way to have such a TCP Listener hosted in a Web Application (ASP.NET)?